# Python lambda does not accept tuple argument

Tags: python, lambda, tuples

I am running Eclipse SDK v3.6 with PyDev v2.6 plugin on two PC, with Linux and Windows.

I would like to pass a tuple as an argument, like:

```
foo = lambda (x,y): (y,x)
print (foo((1,2)))
```

This works on Linux and gives the correct result:

```
> (2,1)
```

On Windows it rises an error:

```
foo = lambda (x,y): (y,x)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Really? Works for me on a Win machine.

Comment: Same Python version on both ?

Comment: "I found that a tuple parameter is deprecated from 3.0 version of Python" More precisely, it is tuple parameter "unpacking" that is removed. And it was not deprecated in 3.0 -- it was *removed* in 3.0.

Comment: The solution is wrong. It should be `lambda q:(q[0],q[1]) in states` (and that's how interjay described it).

Comment: If you are just doing what you show in your first code snippet, just use `def`. If you are applying the lambda to an iterable of tuples, `itertools`' `starmap` automatically unpacks for you, e.g., `starmap(lambda x, y: x + y, ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))) # => (3, 7, 11)`

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You are probably running Python 3.x on Windows, and Python 2.x on Linux. The ability to unpack tuple parameters was removed in Python 3: See [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

You can manually unpack the tuple instead, which would work on both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
foo = lambda xy: (xy[1],xy[0])
```

Or:

```
def foo(xy):
    x,y = xy
    return (y,x)
```

Comment: or `foo = lambda x, y: (y, x)` -> `foo(*(1,2))` (Works on Py3, I don't know for Py2...)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does anyone know of a beautiful functional-programming way to convert a tuple argument into two separate arguments, for readability's sake?

Comment: Your code throws `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error when I execute `lambda xy: (xy[0] + xy[1])`

Comment: @Apurva I tested this and it works. You must be calling the lambda incorrectly.

Comment: It's worth noting that running your code through `2to3`, `modernize`, or `futurize` will catch the lambda and suggest almost this exact same change (except with `x_y` in place of `xy`). Whenever you're porting code from 2.x to 3.x and don't know both languages, it's worth running one of those tools (or an IDE's wrapper around them) at least for a sanity check and hints, if not to actually accept its output.

Comment: This is so miserably ugly. I will always have a soft spot for Python, but this is just awful.

Comment: I also think python needs to improve this. Super ugly

Comment: @JoelCross
"Does anyone know of a beautiful functional-programming way to convert a tuple argument into two separate arguments, for readability's sake?"
Sorry for answering 5 years late... the function you're looking for is called curry!
Curry takes a function of a pair and returns a function of 2 arguments. There's also curry3, which turns a function of a 3-tuple into a function of 3 arguments, etc.
https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=curry
In dynamically typed languages like python, we can usually define autoCurry, which turns a function of N-tuple to a function of N arguments for any N.

Comment: removed in python3, man that's sad.

Comment: @bagrounds In fact, what they want is *uncurry*, e.g. `uncurry(lambda x, y: (y, x))`. An `uncurry` function will turn a `lambda` of two arguments (which is syntactically valid in Python3), into a function of one tuple.