# `key` function for sorting tuples without magic numbers after PEP 3113

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, coding-style, iterable-unpacking

My program is given a source of data with "value" and "number of occurrences" columns, as a collection of tuples `(value, frequency)`. In Python 2.6 or 2.7, I'd do this:

```
ls.sort(key=lambda (value, frequency): -frequency)
```

But Python 3 removed the ability to unpack a tuple parameter. It doesn't hurt quite as much in named functions because one can unpack with an assignment statement in the body of a function ([Nested arguments in python not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607293/nested-arguments-in-python-not-compiling)). But because a `lambda` body cannot use assignment statements, one can't unpack in this way ([Python lambda does not accept tuple argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328312/python-lambda-does-not-accept-tuple-argument)).

[PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) recommends this workaround:

```
ls.sort(key=lambda row: -row[1])
```

But this use of `1` as a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) leaves a bad taste in my mouth. Is the use of such magic numbers idiomatic in Python 3? Or should I create a named function for each case where I had previously used tuple unpacking in a lambda, like this?

```
def negative_of_frequency_from_value_frequency_tuple(value_freq):
    value, freq = value_freq
    return -freq

ls.sort(key=negative_of_frequency_from_value_frequency_tuple)
```

Or should I bug the author of the library that provides these tuples to return [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) instead of plain tuples?

Comment: To avoid the magic number, you could do e.g. `VALUE_INDEX, FREQ_INDEX = range(2)`.

Comment: The use of magic numbers as indexes are fine; if you really don't want an index that could be arbitrarily in the middle use `-row[-1]` which would indicate the last index absolutely.

Comment: To me (and to code checker programs), unused local names are a code smell.  I would use what you call a workaround, `lambda r: -r[1]`, even in 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a single level destructuring, you can get the same effect with a wrapper.

```
ls.sort(key=lambda x: (lambda value, frequency: frequency)(*x))
```

If you need multiple levels, then use the comprehensions

```
ls.sort(key=lambda x: next(-frequency for value, frequency in [x]))
```