# "merging" dictionaries using lambda and map

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I've got the following two dictionaries in python which I need to transform in a way to get the third dictionary

```
    matrikelnummer_zu_note = { 35135135: 5, 60103513: 3, 10981179: 2, 18637724 : 4 }
    note_zahl_zu_string = { 1: "summa cum laude", 2: "magna cum laude", 3: "cum laude", 4: "rite", 5: "non probatum" }

    {60103513: 'cum laude', 10981179: 'magna cum laude', 18637724: 'rite', 35135135: 'non probatum'}
```

So I need to get the values of the first dictionary and replace them with the values linked with the corresponding keys in the second dictionary.

I could solve this doing a simple loop like this:

```
def transform_dict(d1, d2): 
    for x in d1.keys():
        d1[x]=d2[d1[x]]
    return d1
```

But our prof wants us to solve the problem using the `map()` function and `lambda`-expressions.

Now I've started by trying to "build" my solution around a lambda and a map function this way:

```
def transform_dict(d1, d2):
    liste = list(d1.values())
    liste.sort()
    list(map(lambda elem_from_list,dictionary: dictionary[elem_from_list],liste,d2 ))
```

But I get an error in the last line saying `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

I'd *really* appreciate any help solving this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map over the dictionary's items which are key-value pairs, and then for each value, use it as key to get value from another dictionary:

```
dict(map(lambda item: 
  (item[0], note_zahl_zu_string.get(item[1], item[1])), 
  matrikelnummer_zu_note.items()))

#{10981179: 'magna cum laude',
# 18637724: 'rite',
# 35135135: 'non probatum',
# 60103513: 'cum laude'}
```

Comment: @2ps Thanks for the edit. But this raises an error in python 3. You can't unpack tuple in lambda in python 3 anymore. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328312/python-lambda-does-not-accept-tuple-argument)

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate (i.e. map) over a dictionary, it maps over the keys. This explains your error, since your `lambda` has two arguments, and the second receives keys from `note_zahl_zu_string`.

So, something like this should be enough:

```
>>> d1 = matrikelnummer_zu_note
>>> d2 = note_zahl_zu_string
>>> dict(map(lambda k1: (k1, d2[d1[k1]]), d1))
{60103513: 'cum laude', 10981179: 'magna cum laude', 18637724: 'rite', 35135135: 'non probatum'}
```

Comment: worked too, but doesn't it map over key-value pairs instead of the keys?

Comment: @thedood No. Try `for e in some_dict: print(e)`