# Python: how to mutate a subset of dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary `d` already created. I want to change only the values of a certain type. For example's sake, I want to replace strings with their lengths.

The boring way to do this is with a for loop:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        d[k] = len(v)
```

But isn't looping slow?
It can be done with a comprehension. I think this is equivalent to the above:

```
d = {k: len(v) if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in d.items()}
```

I tried it with a map, but these don't work (apparently because I don't understand [something about tuple unpacking in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328312/python-lambda-does-not-accept-tuple-argument)):

```
d = dict(map(lambda k,v: (k, len(v) if isinstance(v, str) else v), d.items()))
d = dict(map(lambda (k,v): (k, len(v) if isinstance(v, str) else v), d.items()))
```

This seems to work, but it's getting big and ugly:

```
dict(map(lambda kv: (kv[0], len(kv[1]) if isinstance(kv[1], str) else kv[1]), d.items()))
```

It seems like this kind of operation would be common, but I can't find specific answers.
What's the correct, Pythonic, and performant way to do it?

Comment: Your `dict` comprehension is correct and imho is the pythonic way to achieve this.

Comment: The for loop doesn't create a new dictionary and replaces only those items that have a string as the value.  The comprehension creates a new dictionary and sets every element, including those which have a non-string as the value.  You ask if looping is slow, but when you need to deal with each item in a set of values there is no alternative.  A comprehension is not magic; it is also a loop.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Aww, not magic? No, I just thought maybe it was more optimized behind the scenes.
So the `for` loop is maybe faster? Or uses less memory?

Comment: Other things being equal you would always prefer the comprehension to the for loop.  But if you have a million items in your dictionary and only two of them are strings, the comprehension would perform 999,998 unnecessary copies whereas the for loop would simply replace 2 values. So a rule like *comprehension=fast, for loop=slow* is too simple.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 the for-loop will definitely use less memory in this case, indeed, it uses a constant amount of memory, vs the comprehension, which requires O(n) memory. But even if your loop were perfectly equivalent to the comprehension, i.e.  it would build  *a new dict instead of modifying an existing one*, then you can only expect marginal speed gains. Comprehensions should be preferred mostly for readability.

Comment: IOW: for-loops **are Pythonic**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer, and CoryKramer already mentioned it.

```
d = {k: len(v) if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in d.items()}
```

This does it, and is the cleanest way.