# How to sort a a Python List on two fields

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have used the following code to merge 2 list items. For example, list 'c' is a creation of list variables 'a' and 'b'

```
a=[['2022', 4], ['2023', 5]]
b=["Random1","Random2"]
c=list(zip(a,b))
```

'c' therefore looks like this

```
Out[]: [(['2022', 4], 'Random1'), (['2023', 5], 'Random2')]
```

i tried to sort 'c' on the 2nd and 3rd column i.e.

```
c_sorted=c.sort(key=lambda i:(i[1],i[2]))
```

however i get the error
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What third item?  The first element of `c` is the two-element tuple `(['2022',4], 'Random1')`. The first element is the list `['2022',4]` and the second is the string `Random1`. What do you want to sort by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly getting 3 equal columns after the merge, but rather a tuple of a list and a plain value as you posted:

```
Out[]: [(['2022', 4], 'Random1'), (['2023', 5], 'Random2')]
```

You want to properly index on the columns and it should work:

```
>>> sorted(c, key=lambda i:(i[0][1], i[1]))
[(['2022', 4], 'Random1'), (['2023', 5], 'Random2')]
```

You might be tempted to attempt something like

```
key = lambda ((year, number), random_string): (number, random_string)
```

but this was actually [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328312/python-lambda-does-not-accept-tuple-argument) in [PEP 3113](https://peps.python.org/pep-3113/)

Alternatively you could truly merge the lists to the result you wanted with this list comprehension instead of the plain `list` call:

```
>>> [x + [y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[['2022', 4, 'Random1'], ['2023', 5, 'Random2']]
```

Now your initial code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

"**IndexError: tuple index out of range**," occurs because the elements in your list c are tuples, and you are trying to access the second and third indices of each tuple. However, the tuples in c have only two elements: the first element from a and the corresponding element from b.
corrected answer can be:

```
a = [['2022', 4], ['2023', 5]]
b = ["Random1", "Random2"]
c = list(zip(a, b))

c_sorted = sorted(c, key=lambda i: (i[0][1], i[1]))
print(c_sorted)
```

**i[0][1] accesses the second element ([1]) of the sublist (i[0]) from a. This is the value you want to use for the initial sorting. i[1] accesses the corresponding element from b. This is the value you want to use as the secondary sorting criterion.**